# Bug in std::basic_string in special case of allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

I use g++ and I have defined a custom allocator where the size_type is byte. 
I am using it with `basic_string` to create custom strings.

The "basic_string.tcc" code behaves erroneously because in the code of

```
_S_create(size_type __capacity, size_type __old_capacity, const _Alloc& __alloc)
```

the code checks for

```
const size_type __extra = __pagesize - __adj_size % __pagesize;
```

But all the arithmetic are byte arithmetic and so `__pagesize` that should have a value 4096, becomes 0 (because 4096 is a multiple of 256) and we have a "division by 0" exception (the code hangs).

The question isn't what should I do, but how could I ask a correction to the above code ? from whom ? (I may implement those corrections).

Comment: The example code does not update `__pagesize`, so your statement "__pagesize ... becomes" hangs in the air, unsupported. Why not post the relevant code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the libray code declares `const size_type __pagesize`.

Comment: when size_type is byte ( unsigned char ) then setting __pagesize=4096 means setting __pagesize=0;

Comment: Perhaps add that you use the Gnu library libstdc++ and not the clan library libc++. Nice how you took a different size_type.

Comment: Why is size_type typedef'ed to char?

Comment: Given that libstdc++'s `basic_string` isn't standard conforming anyway, this may be wasted effort. Have you tried the same with [`__versa_string`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/libstdc++/api/a00021.html)?

Comment: @Zacrath why not? If this allocator can only allocate very small objects, then `char` is appropriate.

Comment: @n.m. Using `char` limits the length of the string to 255. And there shouldn't be a limit without a reason.

Comment: @Zacrath If the type is a template, than it may be used "legally" with various sizes and types. If not let's do it simpler without any template just fixed size. A simple case where a string could be < 255 is when used as a name of a function in a programming language, maybe in a microcontroller so space is limited.

Comment: @So just to be clear, the reason that `size_type` is typedef'ed to `char` is because of limited memory?

Comment: Not necessarily, if the library gives you the right to use any (or at least some parameters) as templates, it should work for them. If you like to define a kind of string that has that size limitation you are allowed theoretically. The minimal memory, is just a pratical example.

Comment: @Zacrath the standard library allows user-defined allocators to limit the size of allicated objects and to define their own size_type presumably because there is a legitimate need, not just out of love to excessive configurability.

Comment: I think if we change anything in libstdc++ my preference would be `static_assert(std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() > __pagesize, "sorry, your allocator is too silly");`

Comment: @JonathanWakely It depends on programming practices ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Before you can request or suggest a change to something like that, you have to establish a strong case that there is indeed a problem that needs to be fixed. In my view there probably is not.

The question is: under which circumstances would it be legitimate (or useful) to define a `size_type` as unsigned char? I am not aware of anything in the standard that specifically disallows this choice. It is defined as

> unsigned integer type - a type that can represent the size of the largest object in the allocation model.

And `unsigned char` is definitely an `unsigned integer type` as per s3.9.1. Interesting.

So is it useful? Clearly you seem to think so, but I'm not sure your case is strongly made out. You could work on providing evidence that this is an issue worth resolving.

So it seems to me the process is:

1. Establish whether `unsigned char` is intended to be included as a valid choice in the standard, or whether it should be excluded, or was just overlooked.
2. Raise a 'standards non-compliance' issue with the team for each compiler that has the problem, providing good reasoning and a repro case.
3. Consider submitting a patch, if this is something within your ability to fix.

Or you could just use `short unsigned int` instead. I would.

Comment: As per my needs, I have already commented out the code, with a simple {if(std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()>=__pagesize_def){
  const size_type __extra = __pagesize - __adj_size % __pagesize;
  __capacity += __extra / sizeof(_CharT);
} So what I am asking is where should I request that patch. As per the fact of standard compliance etc, it is clear and immediate that is just a simple bug, independently of any standard or other consideration, it is just to correct and go on to more interesting work and arguments. Moreover the bug will come back again in shorts if page_size>65536.

Comment: Try http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/bugs/ or https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/appendix_contributing.html.